# How to bring in multiple values from a single XML file?

Tags: xml, powershell, loops

I have developed this Powershell script to parse values from and xml file.  There are 3 rdf sections in the XML file, but I'm only getting the last. I know its overwriting somewhere but I can't figure out where.  I get all the individual values I need, but not multiple lines

```
$docPath = 'C:\ACG\Profium\export_20230203\_http___www.profium.com_docman_ImageSet__objects.rdf'
$xmlFile = [xml]::new(); $xmlFile.Load(( Convert-Path -LiteralPath $docPath ))

# Create an ordered hashtable as a precursor for a PSCustomObject
$ht = [ordered] @{}

# Process all ChildNodes
$xmlFile.rdf.ChildNodes |
    Where-Object Name -match 'Description' | 
        ForEach-Object {
            # Get element text, trim whitespace, replace any line breaks by comma.
            
            $value = $_.about   #.Trim() -replace '\r?\n', ',' 

            # Add hashtable entry (associate name with value)
            $ht[ 'about' ] = $value 
        }

$i = 1 # Counter variable
$xmlFile.rdf.Description.ChildNodes |
    # Filter by Name property (which is either element name or Name attribute) (Can only do 10 fields at a time this way)
    Where-Object Name -match 'modified|normal|creator|created|contentType|originalFileName|contentDescription|description|modifier' | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # Get element text, trim whitespace, replace any line breaks by comma.
        if ($_.'#text' -eq $null){  
            $value = $_.resource 
        }  
        else {  
            $value = $_.'#text' 
        }   #.Trim() -replace '\r?\n', ',' 

        # Add hashtable entry (associate name with value)
        $ht[ "Field$i" ] = $value 
        $i++
    }

[PSCustomObject] $ht| Format-Table -Wrap
```

Here is a sample of my XML - and the 2 sections representing what I'm trying to get to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF  xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#' xmlns:n9='http://www.profium.com/user/' xmlns:n10='http://www.warnermusic.fi/earkisto/' xmlns:n11='http://www.profium.com/imagearchive/2007/' xmlns:n8='http://www.profium.com//images/primary/20170210/' xmlns:profium='http://www.profium.com/schema/v5/' xmlns:rdfs='http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#' xmlns:n12='http://www.profium.com//unknown/primary/20170201/' xmlns:owl='http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#' xmlns:n5='http://www.profium.com/schemas/2001/Sir/' xmlns:n6='http://www.profium.com/archive/' xmlns:n4='http://www.profium.com//images/primary/20150409/' xmlns:n7='http://www.profium.com//unknown/primary/20150401/' xmlns:n13='http://www.profium.com/docman/'>
  <rdf:Description  rdf:about='http://www.profium.com//images/primary/20150409/14285626214390'>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/docman/Image' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/docman/ImageSet' />
    <n6:normal rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com//unknown/primary/20150401/14285626929400' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/archive/ModificationTracked' />
    <n6:thumb rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com//unknown/primary/20150401/14285626920490' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/archive/AccessRestricted' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/archive/FolderMember' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/docman/BinaryContent' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/archive/DescribableObject' />
    <n10:modified rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime'>2015-04-09T09:58:13</n10:modified>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/archive/ArchivedObject' />
    <n6:creator rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/user/CCCD5942-AE3A-7844-468C-EF4BABA20615' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/archive/DigitalContent' />
    <n10:created rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime'>2015-04-09T09:58:13</n10:created>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource' />
    <n5:contentType rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>image/jpeg</n5:contentType>
    <n6:originalFileName rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>appendix vocalist agreement andersen signed.jpg</n6:originalFileName>
    <n5:contentDescription rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>original</n5:contentDescription>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description  rdf:about='http://www.profium.com//images/primary/20150409/14285628755340'>
    <n5:contentType rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>image/jpeg</n5:contentType>
    <n6:normal rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com//unknown/primary/20150401/14285628782060' />
    <n10:modified rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime'>2015-04-09T10:02:02</n10:modified>
    <n6:creator rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/user/CCCD5942-AE3A-7844-468C-EF4BABA20615' />
    <n11:description rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>Darude, Beautiful Alien feat AI AM</n11:description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource' />
    <n6:thumb rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com//unknown/primary/20150401/14285628760340' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/docman/Image' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/docman/ImageSet' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/archive/ModificationTracked' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/archive/AccessRestricted' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/archive/FolderMember' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/docman/BinaryContent' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/archive/DescribableObject' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/archive/ArchivedObject' />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/archive/DigitalContent' />
    <n6:modifier rdf:resource='http://www.profium.com/user/CCCD5942-AE3A-7844-468C-EF4BABA20615' />
    <n5:contentDescription rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>original</n5:contentDescription>
    <n6:originalFileName rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'>appendix vocalist agreement andersen signed.jpg</n6:originalFileName>
    <n10:created rdf:datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime'>2015-04-09T10:01:18</n10:created>
  </rdf:Description>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a short, representative sample of your xml?

Answer (score 0):

You should always use an XML library like Xml Linq to parse xml

```
using assembly System 
using assembly System.Linq
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$Filename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($Filename)
$root = $xdoc.Root
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

foreach($description in $root.Elements())
{
   $elementName = $description.Name.LocalName;
   if($elementName -eq "Description")
   {
      $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
      foreach($element in $descriptions.Elements())
      {
         $elementName = $element.Name.LocalName;
         if($elementName -ne "type")
         {
            $newRow | Add-Member -force -NotePropertyName $elementName -NotePropertyValue $element.Value
         }
      }
   }

   $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}
$table | Format-List
```

Results :

```
contentType        : image/jpeg
normal             :
modified           : 2015-04-09T10:02:02
creator            :
description        : Darude, Beautiful Alien feat AI AM
thumb              :
modifier           :
contentDescription : original
originalFileName   : appendix vocalist agreement andersen signed.jpg
created            : 2015-04-09T10:01:18

contentType        : image/jpeg
normal             :
modified           : 2015-04-09T10:02:02
creator            :
description        : Darude, Beautiful Alien feat AI AM
thumb              :
modifier           :
contentDescription : original
originalFileName   : appendix vocalist agreement andersen signed.jpg
created            : 2015-04-09T10:01:18
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your two sample sections seem pretty much the same.

Second, since you're dealing with xml, you're probably better off using xpath expression to parse it. Putting aside the `PSCustomObject` related issues and focusing only on how to extract some of the values, I would try something like the below.

Note that your sample xml has numerous namespace declarations and you should take those into account in modifying the code:

```
#first, declare the namespaces; as mentioned, I only sampled 3:
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xmlFile.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("rdf", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#")
$ns.AddNamespace("n6", "http://www.profium.com/archive/")
$ns.AddNamespace("n5", "http://www.profium.com/schemas/2001/Sir/")

#locate the main sections:
$abouts = $xmlFile.SelectNodes('//rdf:Description/@rdf:about',$ns)

#within in section, find the target elements:
foreach ($about in $abouts) {
    $creator =  $about.SelectSingleNode('//n6:creator/@*',$ns)
    $normal =  $about.SelectSingleNode('//n6:normal/@*',$ns)
    $contentType =  $about.SelectSingleNode('//n5:contentType/@*',$ns)
    $originalFileName = $about.SelectSingleNode('//n6:originalFileName/text()',$ns)
    $contentDescription = $about.SelectSingleNode('//n5:contentDescription/text()',$ns)
    $modifier = $about.SelectSingleNode('//n6:modifier/@*',$ns)
    echo $about, $creator , $normal, $contentType, $originalFileName.InnerText, $contentDescription.InnerText,$modifier
    
}
```