# Update existing SharePoint Online List Items via PowerShell

Tags: list, powershell, csv, sharepoint-online, hyper-v

I'm exporting a list of VMs from Hyper-V into a CSV, then putting that in a SharePoint Online list.

I can create the list, add a new text column and add list items. However I cannot seem to update the list items. I need to be able to:

1. create list items if they don't exist - this works
2. update list items if they do exist - this doesn't work

Here is the first draft of the script so far:

```
#Config Variables
$vmhost = "<serverhostname>"
$ListName = $vmhost
$folderpath = "C:\scheduled tasks\hyperv-host-vm-collation-scheduled-task"

$output = "$folderpath\$vmhost.csv"
Get-VM -ComputerName $vmhost | Select-Object Name,State | Export-Csv -Path $output -NoTypeInformation
$input = "$folderpath\$vmhost.csv"
$vms = import-csv $input

$SiteURL = "<SharePointOnlineURL>"
 
#Setup Credentials to connect - this will change to use credentials retrieved over REST API
$UserName = ""
$Password = ''

$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, $SecurePassword

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred

#Try to Get the List from the document library
$List = Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName
 
If($List -ne $Null)
{ 
    Write-Host -f Yellow "List exists, updating list"
}
Else
{
    Write-Host -f Green "List does not exist, creating list"
    #Create the list
    $ListName = "$vmhost"
    New-PnPList -Title $ListName -Template GenericList -EnableVersioning
    #Add the State column
    Add-PnPField -List $ListName -Type Text -DisplayName State -InternalName State -AddToDefaultView -ErrorAction Stop
    #Rename Title column to Name
    Set-PnPField -List $ListName -Identity Title -Values @{Title="Name"} -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

The next part is where I am struggling. I've tried so many different ways to loop through the CSV and SharePoint Online list then update the SharePoint Online list based on the CSV values. The below is just my latest attempt.

The issue with this version is that it writes every VM name and state to every list item so the SharePoint Online list ends up with every item being the same. I'm sure my approach is all wrong but can't see the wood for the trees! Is there a circular/chicken and egg dependency here?

```
$ListItemIDs = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields Id

#Update the list
foreach($vm in $vms){

foreach($ListItemID in $ListItemIDs){

If($ListItemID -ne $Null)
{ 
    Write-Host -f Yellow "List item exists, updating list item"
        Set-PnPListItem -List "$vmhost" -Identity $ListItemID -ContentType Item -values @{'Title' = $vm.Name; 'State' = $vm.State;}
}
  Else
{

Write-Host -f Green "List item does not exist, creating list item"

#Create the list items
foreach($vm in $vms){
  Add-PnPListItem -List "$vmhost" -ContentType Item -values @{'Title' = $vm.Name; 'State' = $vm.State;}
                    }
}
                                    }
                        }

Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

I know that both the CSV and SharePoint Online List Items have IDs and/or GUIDs, but am unsure if I need to utilise these. Should I be using an array of the VM names somehow to populate the SharePoint Online List Items?

Edit:

For the moment I've just resorted to deleting all the list items:

```
Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName | Get-PnPListItem -PageSize 100 -ScriptBlock {
    Param($vms) Invoke-PnPQuery } | ForEach-Object {$_.DeleteObject()
    }
```

Then recreating them using Add-PnPListItem

Comment: Use Import-CSV which converts the csv to PS objects.  Then use Where-Object to locate changes.  Finally use Export CSV to write changes back to a file.  I usually read the csv into a variable $table.  Create New rows similar to code in following posting Where I create a new psobject and then added properties using Add-Member.  Finally adding new row to the table.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792368/how-to-bring-in-multiple-values-from-a-single-xml-file/75793832#75793832

Comment: I'm using import-csv in a variable near the beginning already, and I plan to override the CSV file completely via a scheduled task once a day so we don't need to worry about updating the CSV file with deleted or new rows.

Comment: Ideally I would iterate through the SharePoint Online List Items, checking against the CSV then updating with https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPListItem.html

Comment: I'm answering your question : "update list items if they do exist - this doesn't work".  Do not exist means to add new rows.

Comment: I can already create new list items if they don't exist, that works. I can't update existing list items. Updating existing list items doesn't mean adding new rows. Here is some sample data that the CSV and SharePoint Online list both use: Column Names: `Name` and `State`. Name: `Server1` and `Server 2`.  State: `Running` and `Off`

Comment: Sharepoint lists have Internal column names that aren't guaranteed to be the same as what you see in the web UI. I'd recommend verifying the internal column names. you can use Get-PNPField

Comment: For the Name column in the CSV I'm using the Title column in SPO (just with the Display Name as Name)